# Loading Image in RecycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, rx-java2

Collecting images from json in recyclerview. How to load the next pages when we get to the end? I am only learning to use retrofit2, rxjava2. I ask you not to judge strictly and suggest what I am doing wrong. I hang the listener in onBind inside the adapter:

```
@Override public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, final int position) {
Hit hit = hits.get(position);
Picasso.get().load(hit.getLargeImageURL())
        .into(holder.imageViewPreview);
if (loadMoreListener != null && !isLoading && !noMore && position == getItemCount() - 1) {
    isLoading = true;
    loadMoreListener.loadMore();
}
```

I am trying to implement the activation of loading the next page by passing its number to the parameters:

```
adapter.setLoadMoreListener(new ImageAdapter.LoadMoreListener() {
        @Override
        public void loadMore() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Конец", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            page++;
            viewModel.loadImages(searchQuery, page);

            adapter.endLoading();
            adapter.setNoMore(true);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Startup error occurs - Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

LoadImages () method code:

```
 public void loadImages(String query, int page){
NetworkService networkService  =  NetworkService.getInstance();
compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
Disposable disposable = networkService.getJSONApi()
        .getResponse(query, page)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Response response) throws Exception {
                deleteHits();
                insertHits(response.getHits());
            }
        }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to notify the adapter with the following code:

```
recyclerview.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
});
```

also check: https://www.journaldev.com/24041/android-recyclerview-load-more-endless-scrolling

Comment: Thank u. Great link!